# Does it make sense to get the best Kth-fold CV test result from an epoch where train result were bad?

Tags: cross-validation, overfitting

I have been looking for some explanation that could convince me over the right way of thinking about CV. My challenge is related to the automation of the model configuration process due to same kind of problem but different cases (unfeasible joining).

I believe the general CV concept in [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/2352264_A_Study_of_Cross-Validation_and_Bootstrap_for_Accuracy_Estimation_and_Model_Selection) mentioned by [@user0123456789](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/318288/user0123456789) is clear. After reviewing some StackExchange's valuable posts, some concerns persist. I will post them separately (as much as possible) following the running answers.

1. If we have 10-fold cross-validation for a regression model (before any kind of regularization, dropout, etc.): it is said one should get the average of best epoch's test result from each run/fold/sample and perhaps standard deviation as good metrics for selection between models. Now thinking of each isolated run: it's known that test results can have the best fit in some cases even though the opposite is more common. Why should someone skip train results when deciding each best fold's test result for the calculation of metrics? Does a good (not the best) test result followed by a closer train result make sense for the desired generalization? I.e.: based on the figure attached, should the model from epoch ~200 (good train and test results) be passed over by the best test result (epoch ~80, bad train result)? Does it make sense (a good test result taken from a bad for training model)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're right, rules of thumb don't always apply: Don't just ignore train results**. It's a good idea to review test/train results to check for anomalies like a poor train and great test result. This is what you're doing by examining your loss plot, but there are more methods to further analyse this.

A good test result after a bad train result would suggest that there's a discrepancy between train and test sets. When using simple k-folds CV, you can in a given fold have a case where the train set is very complex and the train set is very simple.

---

An example could be imaginary cancer patient data (assuming that most data points are labeled 0 for non-cancer) where you train on labels like this 01100 and test on labels like this 00001. That could, depending on your model, result in a situation where your model predicts all cases as 0, giving bad train results, and very good test results. This is why averaging models can be useful.

**For a regression problem** (meaning continuous data), it's not so easy to visualize the cause of the result. But ***in any case, you should use a scoring function that makes sense for your data***. [To measure your regression model performance, you should plot the model coefficients, β0  and β1](https://towardsdatascience.com/what-are-the-best-metrics-to-evaluate-your-regression-model-418ca481755b). This would give you an actual indicator of model performance.

It does not make much sense to expect a model with a good test result and a bad train result to be better than a model with a good train and test result, because the good test result could be a chance result.

**To sum up, and answer your last question**: No, the model from epoch ~200 should most likely not be passed over by the best test result from epoch ~80, because your plot doesn't adequately visualize the model performance.

---

It's hard to give more precise advice, because you haven't said what type of data you are modeling or given any data examples, so I assumed you were modeling continous data. For binary data (which is more easily modeled and interpreted - so consider if it's possible to convert your data to binary):

You can visually examine your binary model using methods like [a confusion matrix](https://machinelearningmastery.com/confusion-matrix-machine-learning/#:%7E:text=A%20confusion%20matrix%20is%20a%20summary%20of%20prediction%20results%20on,key%20to%20the%20confusion%20matrix.) to see what causes the result.

You should use binary score metrics to examine the model performance - such as [the F1 score - if it's suitable for your data](https://towardsdatascience.com/essential-things-you-need-to-know-about-f1-score-dbd973bf1a3#4e28). If you plot F1 score for each epoch, you'll hopefully see it increasing over time.

Comment: Thank you very much @yes! I have 2 (two) tens of continuous weather variables and 1 (one) continuous label. Models are FNNs. The loss function is MSE, but my metric is nRMSE (normalization by sample's mean value). Label values are discretized and grouped in 10 slices, then selected randomly in a way that keeps almost the same average for each fold. The shape of the error plot is not always the same, the reason I need to automate decision.

Comment: If we consider the metric and the fold forming are right, does it make sense to define a final metric based on the upper value (between train and test samples) plus some arbitrary parameter times the "delta = [abs(train-test)]" value? It seems to me that it makes sense as an arbitrary way to automate the best value's epoch when calculating the Kth-fold test value.

Comment: May I lose something in terms of CV concept? I intend to use the same strategy for the final training.

Comment: Wait woah, so your plot shows MSE, with a best MSE at about 0.5? That doesn't sound so good? Have you tried adding a PCA step in your pipeline? I'm assuming your best epoch metric implies that you'll be looking for the min value in a list, but how do you know you don't have a local minimum? A better formula would probably look for a change in delta. Most modeling frameworks have an early stopping algorithm included, try using the one in yours instead of devising one yourself. https://towardsdatascience.com/the-million-dollar-question-when-to-stop-training-deep-learning-models-fa9b488ac04d

Comment: This figure (borrowed from the internet) is presented only to show the idea (shapes). I've been using early stopping, but existing algorithms (i.e. based on delta_test) were not useful at all times. The idea is to follow the decrease of: upper_value_between_train_and_test + some_alpha_times_abs_of_train-test. In other words: I accept to train while the upper value's sample (train or test) is decreasing and the difference between test and train losses is controlled (also decreasing, or increasing at some fraction of the upper value). It is hard to explain ;). Do you see any evident mistake?

Comment: but can't you just use the patience parameter? Like this:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-stop-training-deep-neural-networks-at-the-right-time-using-early-stopping/

code example from that page:
```es = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', mode='min', verbose=1, patience=200)

mc = ModelCheckpoint('best_model.h5', monitor='val_accuracy', mode='max', verbose=1, save_best_only=True)

# fit model

history = model.fit(trainX, trainy, validation_data=(testX, testy), epochs=4000, verbose=0, callbacks=[es, mc])

# load the saved model

saved_model = load_model('best_model.h5')```

Comment: You need a patience parameter, otherwise you can't know if you're at a local minimum and it gets even lower in a later epoch. From the picture, early stopping without patience would be epoch ~80, but the actual best would be epoch ~190. MAYBE!

A better solution might be to just have a third and seperate set of data not exposed to cv: validation, in order to check if your model is actually performing well on never seen before data, instead of assuming small delta is better. Otherwise you can't really know if epoch ~80 or ~200 is actually best. https://blog.roboflow.com/train-test-split/

Comment: Tks @yes! I've been applying a patience parameter, but when the training stops, a "wrong best" (lower test error but with a not good "delta") result is selected (it is not from the latest epoch). The shapes of the real curves are zigzag and delta errors change a lot from one epoch to another. How could I select the model/epoch where the minimum test error has a concomitant unacceptable training error? That's the reason of my proposal. A third sample would not participate in the internal decision while giving me an idea (confirmation) of generality. If not so good, back to the same point.

Comment: Just to share an extra point to my concerns: after the model is selected by means of cross-validation, I will have to decide when to stop the final training (100% of data). If using a test sample, I will go back to the earlier points. I intend to use an ensemble model to get the prediction values from the mean of the k fold models (from best epochs) outputs (does it make sense?).